# Swarming on Riemannian Manifolds

Tags: differential-equations

I am working on a swarm project on robot operating system,
the control structure of the project is on page 32. Technical implementation is also available on page 32. I have successfully run it.
This implementation includes multihector_controll.nb file, which generates the positions and velocities for the drones in CSV file using the Morse Swarm equation and the python code running in ROS use positioning and velocity data provided by wolfram code in CSV and then move the drones." ref: page 24":
[image: Morse Swarm]
[image: Morse Potential]

The resultant behaviour depends on lambda value and generates the formation according to it:
[image]

This paper contains Three more robot formations like a sphere, hyperbolic and oval which is known as Swarming on Riemannian Manifolds. "ref: page 30, 31".
[image]
[image]

I want to apply Riemannian Manifolds equation instead of Morse Swarm equation which will create the following expected formation:
[image]

I have tried to replace the equation but it is not working. I have done the maximum work, you can download this project from the following [GitHub](https://github.com/MuhammadDanyialKhan/MultiHectorSwarm) link. You can find the wolfram files in "/src/multi_hector/src". Kindly help me to replace the equations. It would be a great help.
Reference:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_MzbUhKXtqVnUuTKQ8mMGVtKEoAq97ly/view?usp=sharing.

Comment: It seems to me that  this problem is a bit too complex for this site. If the manifold is not a simple geometry then computing the geodesic distances will certainly be the bottleneck....

Comment: If the manifold is a submanifold of $R^n$ then guaranteeing to stay on the submanifold will also be an issue. In fact, the ODE becomes then a integro-differential equation which is not so easy to solve. As for the time integrator: Since this is a dynamic ODE, symplectic time integrators might work fine.